# Django - Built project broken

Tags: python, django

So basically, I have a DJANGO project that can be executed and work well. And I don't know why (maybe I upgrade my django or sth) that this is no longer working.

First I try "python3 manage.py runserver" I get this from console:

[image]

So I try to collect the static file with "python3 manage.py collectstatic"

[image]

And I do have "ckeditor" in my static folder

[image]

And I'm sure that my project is work because it still online somewhere.
And notice 1 thing that in the project that my "manage.py" is not turning red. like this
[image]

[image]

I know its just UI behavior but it seems that the project is broken. Anyone has idea bout it?

Comment: There is no reason to post images of code or errors. Copy and paste the *text*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've got a python dependency problem. You've probably added django ckeditor in your INSTALLED_APPS settings, but it's not installed in your (virtual) env.

So have you installed django ckeditor using pip ? It's not related to the static folders or anything, they're not compile time errors. They are 404s.

Comment: what do you mean that i dont install it in my virtual env?

Comment: Checkout the result of "pip freeze | grep ckeditor", see if ckeditor is there maybe. The error you're getting doesn't have anything to do with collectstatic or static files, python cannot import ckeditor in runtime.

Comment: yeah it exists.